# Почему выводит исходный код снизу

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Вот код

```js
  var sourcecode = document.getElementById('source');
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  var compile = document.getElementById('compile');
  var exp = {
   h: new RegExp('H', 'gi'),
   q: new RegExp('Q', 'gi')
  }
  compile.onclick = function() {
   output.innerHTML = '>';


   output.innerHTML += sourcecode.value.replace(exp.h, 'Hello world!<br>')
   output.innerHTML += sourcecode.value.replace(exp.q, sourcecode.value+"<br>")
  }
```

```css
#output {
 padding: 5px;
 width: 50%;
 min-height: 200px;
 background: #000;
 font-family: monospace;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <textarea name="text" id="source" cols="30" rows="10">
HHH
 </textarea>
 <br>
 <button id="compile">Запустить</button>
 <div id="output">
  &gt;
 </div>
```

Вопрос, почему он выводит HHH (исходный код)?

Comment: а почему он не должен выводить HHH? и что должна была делать данная строка: `output.innerHTML += sourcecode.value.replace(exp.q, sourcecode.value+"<br>")`?

Comment: А почему должен?

Comment: Потому что ты сам ее добавляешь в результат

Comment: Если присутствует символ Q То показать исходники

Comment: как ты думаешь, что вернет replace, если не найдет совпадений с переданным регулярным выражением?

Comment: наверное false.

Comment: не угадал, попробуй еще раз :)

Comment: sourcecode.value ?

Comment: внезапно, да? если ничего не менять, все остается так же :)

Comment: Всеравно не понял.

Comment: и что теперь делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что замены происходят *только* с исходной строкой. И когда ничего не поменялось после выполнения

```
sourcecode.value.replace(exp.q, sourcecode.value+"<br>")
```

Результат добавляется в output. Вот и получается *постоянный* вывод исходного кода в конце.

Вместо этого, следующую замену нужно применять *к результату* предыдущей

```
var result = sourcecode.value.replace(exp.h, 'Hello world!<br>');
result = result.replace(exp.q, sourcecode.value + "<br>");
```

или

```
var result = sourcecode.value
                       .replace(exp.h, 'Hello world!<br>');
                       .replace(exp.q, sourcecode.value + "<br>");
```

И только полученный результат добавлять в output.

Например:

```js
var sourcecode = document.getElementById('source');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var compile = document.getElementById('compile');
var exp = {
  h: /H/gi,
  q: /Q/gi
}
compile.onclick = function() {
  output.innerHTML = '>';
  var result = sourcecode.value.replace(exp.h, 'Hello world!<br>');
  result = result.replace(exp.q, sourcecode.value + "<br>");
  output.innerHTML += result;
}
```

```css
#output {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="source" cols="30" rows="10">
HHH
 </textarea>
<br>
<button id="compile">Запустить</button>
<div id="output">
  &gt;
</div>
```